# Is initializing an array of size 2 the same as mallocing a pointer with an array of size 2?

Tags: c, pointers

In my program, I'm creating an array of structs that's basically a value with a buffer of 32 bytes, or a struct that looks like:

```
typedef struct 
{
    long buffer[2];
    int val;
} buffered_val_t;
```

So each array value will have this buffer and a val. The idea behind this is to clear some space in a 64-byte cache line. However, instead of setting buffer[2] outright, is this equivalent to setting the struct as:

```
typedef struct 
{
     long * buffer;
     int val;
} buffered_val_t;
```

And then in another function, initializing buffer with:

```
long *array_one = (long *) malloc (sizeof(long) * 2);

int x;
for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
{
     buffered_val_t[x].buffer = array_one;
}
```

Would the same "buffer effect" be achieved here? Edit: by which I mean, will the same amount of space be cleared in the same parts of the cache?

Comment: What does "buffer effect" mean exactly? If you mean can it be used functionally to store data then yes it can. If you mean will the caching be exactly the same then no. You need to more clearly define what you mean by "same".

Comment: @kaylum the idea is to clear some space in a 64-byte cache line. Will the same amount of space be cleared in both cases?

Comment: When you use the pointer, the struct only contains the pointer, not what it points to.  The struct will not be as big as the case where you allocate the array in the struct.

Comment: If you are trying to manipulate the actual processor cache, you need a lot more control over where things are in memory than either putting an array in a structure or calling `malloc`. Allocating 32 bytes at a time will do nothing to guarantee that the allocation maps to any particular part of cache. To manipulate cache, you may have to allocate one piece of memory that is the size of cache, and then you are guaranteed some part of that memory maps to whatever part of cache you are interested in. Then you will need to do some calculations on the addresses with respect to cache.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are just writing a simulation of cache and are using these structures to implement that, then prefer the array-in-a-structure. Allocating memory separately and assigning its address to a pointer is less efficient and should not be used unless you have some other need, such as keeping the memory beyond the lifetime of the structure.

Answer (score -1):

Functionally same? Yes, they're both valid and achieve the same thing.

With the latter, you may have the additional work that you may want to `free` the malloc'ed memory regions.

On the other hand, if your array is too big, `malloc`'ing - dynamic memory allocation - might be unavoidable because of the potential stack (aka, automatic storage) overflow issue. In your case, I'd suggest to stick with the former as it's only an array of 2.